# Trying to use a for loop for population simulation(2)

Tags: r

Im sorry to say that I have a problem with a for loop, again. I'm trying to save the final number from a population estimate for loop into a new matrix but I am only able to get the population estimate to show up in row 100. I know it relates to breedingPop2 but I cant figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated. Please find the code below:

```
finalPop=matrix(nrow=102, ncol=1)
for(i in 1:100){

SWWAyears=data.frame(iteration=rep(NA,101),pop=NA)
breedingPop<-90000
fallMig<-.825
springMig<-.825
winterSurvival<-rbeta(100,.95,.05)
npFecund<-rbinom(100, 3.0, .9)
pFecund<-rbeta(100, .85,.25)
breedingSurvival<-rbeta(100,.95,.05)

# Set initial starting condition
SWWAyears[1,2]=breedingPop
for(years in 2:101) {
  fallPop<-(SWWAyears[years-1,2]*fallMig)
  for (i in 1:100){
  winterPop<-(fallPop*winterSurvival[i])}
  springPop<-(winterPop*springMig)
        for (i in 1:100){
        summerPop<-(springPop*breedingSurvival[i])
        }
            for(i in 1:100){
            breedingPop2<-((summerPop*.26)*npFecund[i])+((summerPop*.14)*pFecund[i])+(summerPop*.60)
            }
  SWWAyears[years,1]=years
  SWWAyears[years,2]<-breedingPop2             
}
finalPop[i,1]<-breedingPop2
}
```

Comment: your `i` is being updated in each of your `for(i in 1:00)` loops. At the end of the last loop `i` is set to `100`. So, in your `finalPop[i, 1]` assignment, you will always be using `finalPop[100, 1] <- breedingPop2`

Comment: Although, I think you have more fundamental issues with your calculations and it not doing what you think it should be doing. I've updated my solution to try and highlight this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have more fundamental issues with your looping structure and you're not getting the correct results you're expecting. However, the reason for your specific question about only the 100th row being updated is:

Your variable `i` is being updated inside your 'inner' `for()` loops, so by the time you reach `finalPop[i, 1] <- breedingPop2`, `i` always equals `100`.

You need to use a different variable, `j` for example, in your inner `for()` loops.

```
finalPop=matrix(nrow=102, ncol=1)

for(i in 1:100){

  SWWAyears = data.frame(iteration=rep(NA,101),pop=NA)
  breedingPop <- 90000
  fallMig <- .825
  springMig <- .825
  winterSurvival <- rbeta(100,.95,.05)
  npFecund <- rbinom(100, 3.0, .9)
  pFecund <- rbeta(100, .85,.25)
  breedingSurvival <- rbeta(100,.95,.05)

  # Set initial starting condition
  SWWAyears[1,2] = breedingPop

  for(years in 2:101) {
    fallPop <- (SWWAyears[years-1,2]*fallMig)
    for (j in 1:100){
      winterPop <- (fallPop*winterSurvival[j])
    }
    springPop <- (winterPop*springMig)
    for (j in 1:100){
      summerPop <- (springPop*breedingSurvival[j])
    }
    for(j in 1:100){
      breedingPop2 <- ((summerPop*.26)*npFecund[j])+((summerPop*.14)*pFecund[j])+(summerPop*.60)
    }
    SWWAyears[years,1] = years
    SWWAyears[years,2] <- breedingPop2
    }
  finalPop[i,1] <- breedingPop2
}
```

Having said that, using multiple nested `for()` loops is generally not recommended in `R`; you should be able to use matrix multiplication / vectorisation to achieve the same result.

**Other Issues**

your values of `winterPop` and `summerPop` will only ever be `fallPop * winterSurvival[100]` and `springPop * breedingSurvival[100]` respectively. Is this what you intended?

Comment: No, that is not what I intended. Based on your comment I now see that each of my for loop variable names needs to be different to get the appropriate value in the calculation. Am I correct? Also, as for my use of nested for loops, this is how the instructor has taught us to code for this kind of calculation.  I will look into how to make more efficient code but it's very difficult for me to learn this stuff on my own.

Comment: @DonSegundo do you have the underlying maths/formula you're working to - it might be easier to start again from scratch rather than deconstruct your current approach?

Comment: There is no underlying math or formula.  This is a population simulation that starts with a bird population size of 90,000 and incorporates parameters affecting the population during a yearly cycle. Ive incorporated parameters for survival during migratory periods (fallMig and springMig), breeding survival (breedingSurvival), winter survival (winterSurvival), and different categories of offspring production (pfecund and npfecund).  I dont know if that makes any sense to you.

Comment: I think at the very least you should put comments into your code to show what you *think* each loop is doing, and what it should output. Then test each loop individually to see if it is working or not.